# file_put_contents to create file out of public directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to create a file in laravels App/Http/Controller directory
so i had used this code

```
$path = 'App/Http/Controller/';

    $fileName = 'demo.php';

    $contents = "<?php echo 'hello'; ?>";
   
   if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 0755, true);
    }

    $path = $path.$fileName;

    file_put_contents($path, $contents);
```

but this is creating a file with directory in Public folder..

how to get rid of this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting up a Disk

You can setup a disk at `config/filesystems.php` and then benefit from `Storage` facade methods.

**config/filesystems.php**

```
'tmp' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path('..'),
],
```

**Notice:** `public_path()` Starts from `public` folder, you can go one step ahead using `public_path('..')`

### Using Storage Facade

You can now use `Storage` methods such as `allDirectories` and `allFiles` for retrieving directories and files, or `put` for saving new files as thoroughly explained in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files).

```
Storage::disk('tmp')->allDirectories();
Storage::disk('tmp')->allFiles('routes');

// Storing new photo
Storage::disk('tmp')->put('newfile.jpg',$content);
```

Comment: this says Disk [tmp] does not have a configured driver.

Comment: `tmp` is an example that I set. You can name your preferred disk anything you want. Pay attention to the **config/filesystems.php** that I posted and the **key** of the that config.

Comment: yes i did set another name but it gave the same error

Comment: You should use the the exact name you saved in `filesystems.php` at the Storage::disk('**The name you set**')

Comment: If it does not works, try dumping cache using `php artisan cache:clear`